# A trio of questions about radio/smartphones

Tags: audio, radio, telephone, frequency-modulation

1. I know that smartphones can receive FM radio using earbud/built-in antennas, but can they receive amateur radio frequencies (144 MHZ?) and if so, how?

   2. Is there a way to sending out radio waves and have them received as a call by smartphones?
   3. Is there any other way of transmitting audio to smartphones in an area independent of cell towers/satellites etc?

Comment: Set up your own cell tower, you'll need some serious cash and an FCC license

Comment: *I know that smartphones can receive FM radio* That is, if they have a build-in FM receiver. Which not every phone has.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I know that smartphones can receive FM radio using earbud/built-in antennas, but can they receive amateur radio frequencies (144 MHZ?) and if so, how?

No. Any phones with built-in FM tuners will have the tuning limits determined by hardware.

> 2. Is there a way to sending out radio waves and have them received as a call by smartphones?

Yes. Use a mobile network station. That's how they work. You will need a licence for this.

> 3. Is there any other way of transmitting audio to smartphones in an area independent of cell towers/satellites etc?

Yes. Bluetooth and WiFi.

Comment: And regarding 2: You will not get a license unless you're in an obscure country and possibly bribe someone. In the developed world only communications companies get such licenses. If you wonder how much the equipment will cost you cannot afford it. Think at least 4 digit numbers in US $. Solution 3 is the one to go for.